# What does `class Foo < self` do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Looking through the [sourcecode](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-store/blob/fc4cd1bcc2f7a7359c8754285cdbe63a8321e37e/lib/redis/store/namespace.rb#L2) of the redis-store RubyGem, I stumbled upon this syntax I hadn't seen before:

```
class Foo < self
  # ...
end
```

My Google-Fu apparently isn't powerful enough, because I've been able to find nothing that describes what this does.

What I'm *guessing* this does, is somehow reopening Foo, extending it with itself as superclass, thereby making it possible to override methods that can call the original definition as `super`. Am I close?

Comment: Yes, you are close!

Comment: In the linked code, `self` refers to `Redis`, so `class Store < self` is equivalent to `class Store < Redis`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Foo < Bar
end
```

Is how you tell Ruby that `Foo` inherits from `Bar`.

Within a class definition, `self` refers to the class itself:

```
# prints Foo
class Foo
  puts self
end
```

So

```
class Foo
  class Bar < self
  end
end
```

Just says that `Bar` is nested under `Foo` and it inherits from it.

Comment: Nitpick: `Bar` is *not* nested under `Foo`. There is no such thing as nested classes in Ruby. The *constant* `Bar` is defined inside the class `Foo`, but there *is no relationship whatsoever* between the *class* `Bar` and the *class* `Foo`. (Well, except for the fact that `Bar` inherits from `Foo`, but I am referring to the more general case of `class Foo < Qux; class Bar < Garble; end end`.) There are *tons* of Ruby tutorials that talk about nested classes, and there are tons of questions in [tag:ruby] on [so] where people are confused because nested classes don't seems to work, and the …

Comment: … simple reason is that Ruby *doesn't have nested classes*, and we should simply never talk about them as if Ruby did have nested classes.

Comment: @JörgWMittag on the other hand, if `Bar` were not nested under `Foo`, we couldn't use `self` to refer to `Foo` ;-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag is it fair to say that the constant `Bar` is nested under `Foo`, whereas the class `Bar` inherits from `Foo`?

Answer (score 4):

The main thing that you seem to be messing is just this: the superclass portion of a Ruby class definition is an *arbitrary Ruby expression*.

So, something like this is perfectly legal:

```rb
class Foo < if rand < 0.5 then Bar else Qux end end
```

Obviously, this doesn't make sense, but for example, in _why the lucky stiff's brilliant little web micro framework [*Camping*](http://ruby-camping.com), routes are defined like this:

```rb
class Edit < R '/post/(\d+)/edit'
```

and Migrations are defined like this:

```rb
class BlogInitialSchemaCreation < V 1.0
```

In [`ActiveRecord`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), migrations are defined like this:

```rb
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
```

All of this simply uses the fact that whatever is to the right of the `<` in a class definition can by *any arbitrary Ruby expression* which is evaluated when the class definition is evaluated.

Comment: I think the OP was under the impression that `self` in `class Foo < self` refers to the class itself, i.e. `Foo` instead of `Bar`. (hence _"with itself as superclass"_)